# How to fix "The property Content is set more than once" error in XAML when overriding the ContentProperty of ContentPage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, contentproperty

Here is the code I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage
    x:Class="Memorise.DecksTab.CopyDeckPopup"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
    <Label />
    <Label />
</pages:PopupPage>
```

With backing code:
csharp

```
[ContentProperty("Contents")]
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CopyDeckPopup : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    StackLayout contentStack { get; } = new StackLayout()
    {
        Spacing = 0,
        Padding = new Thickness(0),
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
    };
     public IList<View> Contents { get => contentStack.Children; }

     public CopyDeckPopup(string clickedDeckName, string clickedDeckDescription)
     {
         BindingContext = new CopyDeckPopupViewModel(clickedDeckName, clickedDeckDescription);
         InitializeComponent();
         Content = contentStack;
     
}
```

In the first **XAML** I am getting an error on the 2nd `Label` saying

> The property "Content" is set more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I can reproduce the behavior.**

**Nevertheless**, on my side even though **VS** displays that warning/error if i run the project it deploys correctly and both labels are displayed.

It seems that **VS** does not recognize that the `ContentProperty` is being **overriden**, and supposes instead that you are trying to add both `Label`s to `Content`, which is wrong since you are adding them to your custom `ContentProperty` `Contents`!

Please run the project and let me know if the deploy fails...

### UPDATE

***The whole issue looks to me like a limitation of VS. At the end it is just a warning, and you should be able to ignore it without any danger.***

If on the other hand you opt to set the labels on code you could write

```cs
public CopyDeckPopup(string clickedDeckName, string clickedDeckDescription)
{
    BindingContext = new CopyDeckPopupViewModel(clickedDeckName, clickedDeckDescription);
    InitializeComponent();
    Content = contentStack;
    Contents.Add(new Label() { Text = "ABC" });
    Contents.Add(new Label() { Text = "DEF" });
}
```

But now this looks redundant since as i understand [ContentProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpropertyattribute?view=xamarin-forms)'s is an attribute that the

> XAML processor uses to determine the content property.
>
> Decorating types with ContentPropertyAttribute allows shorter XAML syntax.

If you code everything on **C#** just use the good old `Stacklayout` and write your code like

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CopyDeckPopup : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    public CopyDeckPopup(string clickedDeckName, string clickedDeckDescription)
    {
        BindingContext = new CopyDeckPopupViewModel(clickedDeckName, clickedDeckDescription);
        InitializeComponent();

        StackLayout contentStack = new StackLayout()
        {
            Spacing = 0,
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Children =
            {
                new Label() { Text = "ABC" },
                new Label() { Text = "ABC" }
            }

        };

        Content = contentStack;
     
}
```